# How to represent multiple text parts in an ElementTree element?

Tags: python, python-2.7, elementtree

I'm using ElementTree to handle some html. I think html is an xml language, so that should be ok.

In html, you can have tags inside text:

```
<p>
This paragraph <em>has some</em> emphasised words.
</p>
```

So the "p" element has some text ("This paragraph "), a child element ("em") and some more text (" emphasised words.")

But ElementTree elements have a text attribute, which is a string. The child elements are in a list, but the text is all together in one string.

How do I represent this html in ElementTree? Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to parse it?

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def processElem(elem):
    if elem.text is not None:
        print elem.text
    for child in elem:
        processElem(child)
        if child.tail is not None:
            print child.tail

xml = '''<p>
This paragraph <em>has some</em> emphasised words.
</p>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
processElem(root)
```

gives:

```
This paragraph 
has some
 emphasised words.
```

Or are you trying to modify the HTML?

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring
top = Element('p')
top.text = 'This paragraph '
child_with_tail = SubElement(top, 'em')
child_with_tail.text = 'has some'
child_with_tail.tail = ' emphasised words.'
print tostring(top)
```

gives:

```
<p>This paragraph <em>has some</em> emphasised words.</p>
```

Comment: Ahhh, so you are saying that the text after each embedded element, up to the next embedded element, lives in the tails of the embedded elements?

Comment: Yes that is correct. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects